# FX REQUEST: Jamaican Walla + Stingers

Tags: request, walla

EXT DAY - Poor Jamaican town.

Lonely kid walks down the street and all we see are birds and a few dogs. So we want convey activity in this scene where there really is none.  I have added some sounds of people in there houses with the windows open (doings dishes and general fiddling about), but I think it would be great to add a layer of Jamaican voices.

Something like a mother yelling at her kids, or just conversation. This is a very short moment so I wouldn't need much.

If you have something like this, or can recommend a library...Lets talk!

Thank you,

Chris

Comment: Do you mean callouts in addition to walla?

Comment: Yes.  The actual voice that can rise up out of the walla. I have never had the budget to record this kind of stuff so my terminology might be a bit off. 

Comment: This is an old question - 9 years ago it would have been on topic, but not any more.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a jamican granular synth on an insert. Duh. Usually for specific call outs like that an ADR group loop crew will come in with certain cues and bring the BG people to life with relevant dialogue that will most likely be mixed down with the BG walla, but in your case the hum of people library might have some Jamaican call outs, or just record it yourself and post process it. Do some wild takes of your best impressions, maybe while watching cool runnings for inspiration. Great movie regardless.

Comment: Who makes the "Hum of People" Library?  initial google searches not turning up much. I will not be supported by loop group for this one. 

Comment: I'm sorry the hum of voices is what I meant.

Comment: Are you referring to DigiFX library?  That's what they tag their foreign walla metadata with "hum of voices" (honestly a little annoying to me since crowd/walla usually aren't in the tag)

Answer (score 0):

try going through Chatter, "talking people" stuff like that on http://freesound.org/ if it just have to be short you should be able to find something you can use. i always find something cool

Comment: It's also worth considering that there are certain limitations of legal usage as well with Freesound.